# What is KeepAlive in Angular Application?

Tags: angular, keep-alive, ng-idle

This question sounds simple but it seems like there is not much explanation on the web.
I am trying to implement ngIdle, and had followed some guides from the internet and they included keepAlive in the implementation. But it didn't really explain what is the keepAlive doing there.

```
setIdle(5) // this fire up the timeout notification modal after 5 seconds
setTimeout(5) // this creates a timer that lasts for 5 seconds after the notification modal is shown
keepalive.interval(15) // what is it doing there and what is the impact on the angular application?
```

So far, when I read online, most of the keepAlive explanation is related to TCP connection and how it handles these connection/threads. But what about in the context of angular application?

Appreciate if can provide some basic explanation on this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In short, if you want to detect when a user is active, then stops the activity, use the keepalive to reset the date-time of the last movement.